# AMP pages indexed by Google are not being shown when searched on mobile

Tags: amp-html

We have created AMP version of news pages for the site https://www.team-bhp.com. Most of the AMP pages are indexed by Google without any error but when a user searches on Google using mobile, Google is showing the actual desktop webpage instead of the corresponding AMP page.

Here's a specific example:

Desktop page: https://www.team-bhp.com/news/bajaj-chetak-rivaling-tvs-electric-scooter-spied

AMP page: https://www.team-bhp.com/news/bajaj-chetak-rivaling-tvs-electric-scooter-spied?amp

Google console shows that the desktop page has been indexed:

[image: Google search console shows page as indexed]

Clicking on AMP link shows that the AMP page is valid:

[image: Google search console shows AMP page being valid]

When I search for this page in Google via my cell phone's Chrome browser, I see the desktop page as search result. I don't see AMP page at all.

Any idea how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait a little to the google robots crawl your site.
To speed up indexing I suggest you create `Sitemap` and set correct `lastmod` date field for this url like below:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://www.team-bhp.com/news/bajaj-chetak-rivaling-tvs-electric-scooter-spied</loc>
  <lastmod>2020-01-16T20:32:11</lastmod>
</url>
```

> Crawling and indexing are processes which can take some time and which
>   rely on many factors. In general, we cannot make predictions or
>   guarantees about when or if your URLs will be crawled or indexed.
>   Crawling and indexing an AMP page is the same as crawling and indexing
>   a regular web page.

For more detail:
- [AMP Indexing FAQs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/2097038)
- [My site isn't indexed yet!](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1050724?hl=en&ref_topic=4558960&vid=0-789350979684-1551890717870)

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile Version of your website does not contain the required relation to your amp page i.e.

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="link to amp page">
```

Though you have the same present on the desktop version, google crawler needs the above-mentioned relation to be present on the mobile version of the website. Just add this link tag to your mobile website and Google Crawler will know that there is a corresponding amp page for the webpage present.

Due to link tag present on the desktop version, Google Crawler was able to index your AMP page. And due to missing tag on Mobile, Google Crawler was unable to link your AMP page to mobile page.